# Using PIP with 2 copies of 2.7

Tags: pip, anaconda

I am running windows 7. I have a copy of 2.7.10 in c:\python27
I have also used Anaconda to download another version of 2.7.10 to c:\Users\Alan\Anaconda. Anaconda seemed the simplest way to get iPython  to read a notebook (on kalman filters).

I need to install a module called filterpy.
"pip install filterpy " updates the c:\python27 copy but does nothing to the other version.
Where does pip look to find where Python is and how do I change that.

My proposed work around is to reinstall the anaconda but use Python 3.4. I understand I can then do pip27 and pip34. Is that correct. I suppose it is time to move to pyton 3 as all packages now seem to support it.

Alan

Comment: I have uninstalled the Anaconda2.7 and installed the anaconda 3.4 as mentioned above. My hopes that pip3.4 would work proved wrong - the command is not recognized. (pip2.7 does work with the 2.7 version)

Comment: Succeeded ! From start menu>All Programs>Anaconda(64bit)>Anaconda command prompt I opened a command window. Inside that pip worked on the Anaconda python 3.4